# How to use NetBeans Java CVS Client?

Tags: java, api, netbeans, client, cvs

I'm trying to access CVS  using NetBeans Java CVS Client.

I'm able to checkout projects but my requirement is to get `TAG` name for files in CVS.ex Tag at the head of a file.

I have searched extensively and found `TAGCOMMAND` class but don't know how to use it with
`Client.excecuteCommand(command)` method.

Can anyone suggest or show some sample code on how to get CVS tag for files using NetBeans Java CVS Client?

Answer (score 4):

The answer may be a little late, however here is some example code using the tag command.
The usage is rather simple.

1) create client.

```
PServerConnection con = new PServerConnection(getCVSRoot());
con.setEncodedPassword(StandardScrambler.getInstance().scramble(password));

GlobalOptions globalOptions = new GlobalOptions();
globalOptions.setCVSRoot(getCVSRoot().toString());

client = new Client(connection, new StandardAdminHandler());

// this line is important, because otherwise you'll get a 
// NullpointerException!
client.setLocalPath(localPath);
```

2) create tag command

```
TagCommand tagCmd = new TagCommand();
tagCmd.setTag(tag);
tagCmd.setOverrideExistingTag(true);
```

3) execute

```
client.getConnection().open();
boolean success = client.executeCommand(cmd, globalOptions);
client.getConnection().close();
```

I used the newest version from [1].

regards Richie

[1] http://netbeans.org/projects/versioncontrol/downloads/